# Omniverse USD Composer 2023.1.1 installation fails at "omni.create.warmup.bat"

Tags: omniverse

Trying to install Omniverse USD Composer 2023.1.1 for the fifth time, with run as admin and not. Every time it gets stuck at  "omni.create.warmup.bat"

Does anyone have a solution or some hints?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Win11 22H2 22621.2134; i9-13900H; Mobile RTX 4080

Comment: Turn off firewall, install it, then turn on firewall.